# MeBo 2.0 on ROS?

Tags: ros, web

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All, I’m a beginner with ROS. I have it up and running just fine, and have completed the basic Turtle sim. I also have a book and some other literature on ROS, and have a pretty good idea on how ROS basically works.

I have a robot toy called a [MeBo 2.0](http://meborobot.com)

The robot has both and Android and iOS application. They way the robot is controlled is to connect to its WiFi, and then you are presented with a view through its camera with a soft button control overlay on the screen. You can go forward backwards, etc, and control the manipulator.

There is a project out on the web that shows the MeBo web-API, but I can’t seem to make the MeBo respond with HTTP-only commands (I think it’s my syntax???). See for details: [mebo-api](https://github.com/crlane/mebo-api)

My question is, is it possible to control the MeBo 2.0 from a laptop running ROS (Ubuntu 16.04LTS Kinetic) to control the robot with HTTP commands through WiFi, and is it possible to import the camera preview page from the MeBo’s web page and use OpenCV to do basic navigation?

The MeBo itself uses a Sonix Access Point camera board similar to the SkyViper GPS drone (less GPS of course). Although firmware is available for most of Rocket Toys products, I have yet to find the actual firmware source for the MeBo 2.0 on their github site [SkyRocket Toys](https://github.com/SkyRocketToys)

I would think this is possible, and was thinking of having the MeBo carry a ROS-enabled Raspberry Pi with Astro-Pi Sense Hat for a mobile solution. I know from reading some of the ROS tutorials, the MeBo would have to be defined with a URDF file, but I don’t have much information on how I would go about adding a consumer toy robot like the MeBo 2.0

Any help, thoughts or suggestion will be appreciated. As I mentioned I have a ROS beginner, and I’m learning as much as I can on my own.

Thank you!

---

Edit: Thank you for your prompt reply!

One note of interest is, that I've actually opened the MeBo 2.0 to see what is on the inside. The camera head has a camera and Sonix AP board with a speaker. That board communicates through a ribbon cable of sorts to the motor board in the base. The motor board has both a serial interface and a SW debug port on it. The drive train of the robot consists of a central motor for each pair of wheels... both left side and right side are each driven by an independent motor through a series of gears to give the MeBo 2.0 four wheel drive. The front axle of each drive train is internally connected to a simple wheel encoder. Feedback for the arm position consists of analog voltages going to the motor board.

Although all of the sensors exist, there is no "diagnostics web page" for the MeBo 2.0, only status pages. The Sonix AP does seem to have a NVRAM page with settings that can be read and altered, but there seems to be no true feedback through the Web Interface other than a visual reference to the operator of the toy.

I suppose if I had enough time to dedicate to reverse engineering the motor control board, it might be possible to communicate directly to the onboard serial port and drive the motor control board directly.

I wonder also if it is possible to somehow import the streaming video from its status page directly into ROS so that OpenCV can be used to do simple tracking or navigation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279030/mebo-2.0-on-ros?/) by [NexxuSix](https://answers.ros.org/users/33171/nexxusix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-01-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-09**:
@NexxuSix: please don't post answers unless you are *answering* your own question. For everything else, update your original question or use comments to interact with other posters.

**Comment by [ihab](https://answers.ros.org/users/56804/ihab/) on 2020-07-19**:
hi NexxuSix, did u manage to find how to control MeBo 2.0 via HTTP? all the available interfaces are for MeBo v1.

could you please share any related info

**Comment by [somerandomperson412](https://answers.ros.org/users/38512/somerandomperson412/) on 2020-07-21**:
Hey if you are looking for mebo 2.0 devolpment please chwck out my mebo 2.0 discord! https://discord.gg/gQsr3de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For people googling for this in the future, I had help with some users on the Letsrobot.tv Website, to hack this robot, and our API is open source on this github https://github.com/meborobot/runmyrobot
it includes the Video API, and Controlls, arms, Claw, Wrist, and turning speed
Feel free to download it! Lots of love! :)

---

Originally posted by [somerandomperson412](https://answers.ros.org/users/38512/somerandomperson412/) with karma: 26 on 2018-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [somerandomperson412](https://answers.ros.org/users/38512/somerandomperson412/) on 2020-07-21**:
Edit! We now have a discord page for mebo 2.0 and mebo 1.0 devolpment! Feel free to join it! https://discord.gg/gQsr3de